# AJAX updating todo list in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm trying to convert my todo list app to use AJAX . Here is my update action of TasksController :

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

def update
  @list= List.find(params[:list_id])
  @task=@list.tasks.find(params[:id])
  @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to [current_user,@list], notice: 'Task completed' }
   format.js
  end
 end

end
```

tasks/update.js.erb :

```
<% if @task.completed? %>
$('#edit_task_<%= @task.id %>').appendTo('#completed_tasks');
<% else %>
$('#edit_task_<%= @task.id %>').appendTo('#incomplete_tasks');
<% end %>
```

This is my lists/show.html.erb which lists out all tasks for a particular list :

```
<h3>Unfinished Tasks</h3>
 <div class="tasks" id="incomplete_tasks">
 <% @list.tasks.incomplete.each do |task| %>
  <%= form_for [current_user,@list,task], remote:true do |f|  %>
   <%= f.check_box :completed %>
   <%= f.submit %>
   <%= f.label :completed, task.description %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
<h3>Finished Tasks</h3>
<div class="tasks" id="completed_tasks">
  <% @list.tasks.completed.each do |task| %>
      <%= form_for [current_user,@list,task], remote: true do |f|  %>
          <%= f.check_box :completed %>
          <%= f.submit %>
          <%= f.label :completed, task.description %>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
<div class="tasks" id="completed_tasks">
  <% @list.tasks.completed.each do |task| %>
      <%= form_for [current_user,@list,task], remote: true do |f|  %>
          <%= f.check_box :completed %>
          <%= f.submit %>
          <%= f.label :completed, task.description %>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
</div>
```

So, I don't quite understand the tasks/update.js.erb code.

```
$('#edit_task_').appendTo('#completed_tasks');
```

In the above code, from which html file are we taking the contents of this div :

Where does that div come from ? Please tell me if my question is unclear ,I'll try and rephrase it . Just to be clear , my code works , but I don't know why ?

Comment: I got the answer. The `<div id="edit_task_id"></div>` was present inside the `<div id="incomplete_tasks">`. When the checkbox is ticked, we find that div and append it to the `<div id='completed_tasks">`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do a ajax request to your update method in the controller, the tasks get updated and it responds back with data in the `format.js`. After it responds, the update.js.erb gets called which updates the different elements in the page, from which you sent the ajax request, with the updated tasks.

In you update.js.erb,

```
<% if @task.completed? %>
$('#edit_task_<%= @task.id %>').appendTo('#completed_tasks');
<% else %>
$('#edit_task_<%= @task.id %>').appendTo('#incomplete_tasks');
<% end %>
```

there is a @task variable, which is the new task. If the task is completed, then it adds the task to the complete_tasks div - else it appends to the incomplete_tasks div.

Completed Tasks  - `<div class="tasks" id="completed_tasks">`

Incomplete Tasks - `<div class="tasks" id="incomplete_tasks">`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.I understand the outline of how it works. But in this code :                                            `$('#edit_task_<%= @task.id %>').appendTo('#completed_tasks');` We are appending a `<div id='edit_task_ id`> to the `<div id="completed_tasks"`. What I don't understand is , From where are we taking the "edit_tasks_id" div ?